# MySQL Replace String "John Doe" with "John D"

Tags: mysql, string, replace

Have a large name table all as string "Name Surname"

Need to update the entire table, setting the string to be "Name FirstLetterOfSurname" ie. "John Citizen" becomes "John C".

Seems easier to do via PHP eg.

```
$name = "John Doe";
$expl = explode(' ', $name);
echo $expl [0].' '.$expl[1][0];
John D
```

wondering about a query to just update the database.

Help Appreciated?

Comment: What did you try??

Comment: Why not do so via PHP, get the logic working there, and paste it in your question?

Comment: updated with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd find the location of the space, and take a substring of one character more than that:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, LOCATE(' ', name) + 1)
FROM   mytable
```

Of course, this can also be done as an update instead of just querying the string in the right format:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    name = SUBSTR(name, 1, LOCATE(' ', name) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the database, please use the following query:

```
UPDATE TestTable 
SET FirstName = CONCAT(LEFT(FirstName, INSTR(FirstName, ' ')) , LEFT(SUBSTRING(FirstName, INSTR(FirstName, ' ') + 1), 1)) ;
```

Please find the <kbd>[`Working Demo`](http://rextester.com/YYOH40287)</kbd> with sample data.